# Flexiable update in Linq To Sql

Tags: linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

Using Linq To Sql/Entities we have enough flexibility to write select queries

But what about update queries.

What if i need to do something simple like that:

`UPDATE suppliers

   SET supplier_name =  (SELECT customers.name
   FROM customers
   WHERE customers.customer_id = suppliers.supplier_id)`

Using Linq to Sql i need to run a lot of update queries to get ti done.
First i need to select the entity which i need to update and then i need to update each of them, seams to be very slow.

Is there any way to make it simple, or there is only store procedure mapping may help in such case?

Comment: I don't have the ability to edit questions yet so I'm offering this as a suggestion ... If you update your question title to something like "Linq to SQL Batch Updates" you might get more answers.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [PLINQO](http://www.plinqo.com).  It added batch updates / deletes plus a whole lot more to LINQ to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

For batch operations like this I would go straight to SQL. In LINQ to SQL you can use [DataContext.ExecuteCommand()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand.aspx) for this. For example:

```
db.ExecuteCommand("UPDATE suppliers SET supplier_name = (SELECT customers.name FROM customers WHERE customers.customer_id = suppliers.supplier_id)");
```

If you believe that inline SQL is evil, have a look at [this post by Terry Aney](http://www.aneyfamily.com/terryandann/post/2008/04/Batch-Updates-and-Deletes-with-LINQ-to-SQL.aspx) on enabling batch updates and deletes in LINQ to SQL. I have no experience with this but it looks interesting.

Comment: Inline sql is evil. It is very bad that there is no Linq syntax for update. I am looking something like that http://www.hookedonlinq.com/UpdateOperator.ashx but looks like for Linq to SQL it is not exist, design does not allow to have such operation..

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to another possible solution.